# jquery javascript verify

Tags: javascript, jquery, verification

I am having some trouble with my verification. Here, an input is being checked that it is a number, is not = to nothing, and it is greater than or = to 3 and less than or = to 12. 
For some reason, I am only able to successfully verify the first part. I cannot get the ">3= && <=12" to work, plz help.

```
}else if(question_pos==2){
        if( $("#myinput").val() != "" && Number($("#myinput").val() ) && $("#myinput").val() >= "3" && $("#myinput").val() <= "12" ){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
```

This is the problem part

```
$("#baseline_05_ft").val() >= "3" && $("#baseline_05_ft").val() <= "12"
```

Comment: try to put that in parenthesis.. `$("#myinput").val() != ""  && ($("#myinput").val() >= "3" && $("#myinput").val() <= "12") `

Comment: This I have tryed, It did not work for me. I return false no matter what.

Comment: and Number($("#myinput").val() works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First with javascript you should be using the `===` operator when doing logical comparisons. Second your problem part is comparing two strings, not numbers. Try converting them to a number first.

```
var myInput = parseInt($('#myinput').val(), 10); //always declare a base when doing parseint
if(myInput >= 3 && myInput <= 12){
    //its valid do stuff to it
}
```

Comment: You forgot to use `!==`, the counterpart to `===`. Also, I've found that compare with `0` is not needed as it's outside of the range.

Comment: `====` 4 eqs? Are you sure about this?

Comment: Thank you! this is exacly what I needed, with a minor alteration. if($('#myinput').val() != 0 && $('#myinput').val()  >= 3 && $('#myinput').val()  <= 12){

Comment: That alternation should not be needed as 0 is not between 3 and 12.

Comment: You also do not need to call your selector and .val() every time. It would be better to store it in a variable as I and many other answers have.

Comment: Yes I should do just that, I am learning how to code as I go, sometimes I don't see the obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is messy, that is probably what causes the error.

Write it like so:

```
var value = parseInt($("#myinput").val(), 10 /*radix*/);
if (isNaN(value) === false && value >= 3 && value <= 12) {
    // ..
}
```

Never compare strings where you mean numbers. Compare what you should be comparing. It makes the code easier to read and understand.

---

This also allows you to use strict comparison (`!==` and `===`) as:

```
3 === 3; // true
3 === "3"; // false
3 == "3"; // true
```

I've never found a case where you want to use `==` instead of `===`.

Comment: I don't think his messy code was the _reason_ for the error. Rather it was his lack of understanding about how to do logical comparisons in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You should convert it to integers-

```
var myVal = parseInt($("#myinput").val(), 10);
if(!isNaN(myVal) && myVal >= 3 && myVal <= 12) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: You should always use a base parameter when using parse int `parseInt(string,base)` otherwise javascript might misinterpret your string in octal when you meant decimal.

Comment: "misinterpret'? Isn't it default to 10?

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev Default ain't 10. Try this - `parseInt("100")!==parseInt("0100")`

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev it is not the default. Javascript will attempt to infer what base the number is in and can often guess wrong.

Comment: @Sann "As of ECMAScript 5, the default is the decimal radix (10)." http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp#gsc.tab=0

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev you can't always assume the browser implementations of the standard are correct. I would rather err on the side of caution than assume they are implementing the standard correctly.

Comment: The radix parameter that should go to `parseInt` is not in the right place. Also, please don't link to w3schools, it's not very good as a JavaScript resource (they get stuff wrong).

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev also older browsers do not follow the new standards so this should not be relied on for general development.

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev In this case- `parseInt("0100")` it will be interpreted as Octal because it is prefixed with "0". Well, w3school says otherwise but I've checked it on Chrome 23 and Firefox 19.

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev w3 schools is often wrong as well. A better resource for documentation would be the Mozilla developer network https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript

Comment: I guess, you guys are right, w3 were just the first link on "parseInt Javascript".

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing strings, not numbers. There is no value that compares lexically greater than `"3…"` but lower than `"1…"`.

```
if (question_pos==2) {
    var strVal = $("#myinput").val();
    var val = Number(strVal);
    return strVal != "" && !isNaN(val) && val >= 3 && val <= 12;
}
```